# Number of nearby elements

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a set of $N$ real numbers selected from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$. What is the expected number of elements of $X$ that lie within $x$ of one another? That is to say, what is the expected number of $X_i\in X$ such that $|X_i - X_j| < x$ where $i < j$?

I suspect the answer scales like $x N^2$, at least for $x\ll 1/N$, but I can't really figure out how to formalize this in a good way.

Comment: Do you mean:  find the number of pairs $(p_i, p_j)$ with $i<j$ such that $|p_i-p_j|<x$? If so, then I'd use indicator variables.  For each such pair, let $I_{i,j}$ be $1$ if the pair $(p_i, p_j)$ is good and $0$ otherwise.  Now just compute the probability that a randomly selected pair is good.

Comment: @lulu could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Let $\psi$ be the probability that a randomly selected pair is good.  Then the answer is $\psi$ times the number of pairs, so $\psi\times \frac {N(N-1)}2$.  And $\psi$ is easy to compute.  If you do it on a circle instead of the interval it is easy to see that $\psi=2x$, for instance.  On the interval, you need to handle the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see this, observe that the probability that a point lies in the interval $[a - x,a + x]$ is
$$P_a = \min{1,a + x} -\max\{0,a - x\}\,.$$
Integrating over $a\in[0,1]$, we find that the average probability is
$$P = \int_0^1{\rm d}a P_a = x(2 - x)\,.$$
Thus, summing over all points (without double counting) we have
$$\langle N \rangle = x(2 - x)\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}\,.$$